# Overloading '+' in a class, using objects from another class

Tags: c++

" Define a class named Number that has as private attribute a double variable. The class contains an
explicit empty constructor, a constructor with a parameter and an accessor method that displays the value of
the stored variable.Write a class called Mathematics that has as attribute an instance created from the first
class and overloads the arithmetical operator '+'.Each method calculates the appropriate result by
considering the data extracted from the Number object."
-The problems asks me to overload the '+' operator, for adding two numbers from the Number class, but the overloading needs to be in the Mathematics class.
/*The error that i have says: "No operator '+' matches these operands. "and it appears at the line at which i add my 2 objects in main().How can i solve this?*/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class Mathematics;

class Number 
{
private: 
    double a;
public:
    Number() { a = 0; }
    Number(double b)
    {
        a = b;
    }
    double get_a()
    {
        return a;
    }
    double set_a(double x)
    {
        a = x;
    }
};

class Mathematics
{
    Number b;
public: 
    Number operator-(Number &d);
    Number operator*(Number &d);
    Number operator/(Number &d);

    Mathematics(Number x)
    {
        b = x;
    }
    Mathematics() { b = 0; }//explicit constructor with no parameters

    Number operator+( Number& d)
    {
        Number c;
        int x;
        x = b.get_a() + d.get_a();
        c.set_a(x);
        return c;

    }

    double show()
    {
        return b.get_a();
    }

};

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nEnter the second number: ";
    cin >> b;
    Number c(a);
    Number d(b);
    Mathematics ob;
    ob = c + d;
    cout<<endl<<ob.show();

}
```

Comment: Please try to copy-paste the assignment text in full and complete into the question. Right now it makes no sense.

Comment: `The problems asks me to overload the '+' operator, for adding two numbers from the Number class, but the overloading needs to be in the Mathematics class` That's impossible, you must have misunderstood the assignment.

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve]. There's way more code than what's needed. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @john [It can be done](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aRi_TD) in an obscure way, but I agree that OP probably misunderstood something.

Answer (score 4):

So I think this is what you are meant to do. Although it makes not very much sense it is at least possible

```
class Number
{
    double a;
public:
    double get_a()
    {
        return a;
    }
};

class Mathematics
{
    Number b;
public:
    Mathematics(Number x)
    {
        b = x;
    }
    Mathematics operator+(const Mathematics& x) const
    {
        return Number(b.get_a() + x.b.get_a());
    }
};
```

So you are overloading operator+ in the Mathemetics class to add two Mathemetics objects, creating a new Mathematics object. But you use the Number attribute that each Mathematics object has.

That's the best sense I can make of some strange requirements.

Of course if you are unsure of what you have been asked to do (which is quite understandable) then you really should ask your teacher.